# How to eliminate 'Hibernate audit tables are missing' WARN message during JUnit tests

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, testng, hibernate-envers

I am writing JUnit tests using Hibernate + Envers. My test works fine but my log is full with the following and simmilar annoying WARN messages:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_AUD
```

I have tried to found the way to turn off Envers during tests but I could not found anything.

This is one of the complete WARN message in the log:

```
INFO - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
INFO - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
INFO - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
INFO - Envers integration enabled? : true
WARN - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:151)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:109)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.delegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:123)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:208)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:125)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.persist(JtaEntityManager.java:193)
        at com.a.b.dao.BaseDAO.persist(BaseDAO.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
        at xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxDAO$$LocalBeanProxy.persist(com/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxDAO.java)
        at xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxDAOTest.testFindByxxxxxxxx(xxxxxDAOTest.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_AUD
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_AUD
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 83 more
```

How can I get rid of these WARN messages?

Comment: Which dialect are you using?

Comment: I use org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

Comment: Can you enable the SQL logging and update your post with the SQL statement Hibernate is executing that leads to this WARN message?

Comment: I updated the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with `HSQL`.

The problem exists depending on the value provided to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` setting.  Basically some of the values cause the schema management tooling to execute a series of *ALTER* and *DROP* statements on the database to guarantee there are no artifacts from prior test runs.

The underlying issue is that `HSQL` does not support the notion of executing an `ALTER` statement that executes a`DROP CONSTRAINT` using an *`IF EXISTS`* clause; so you end up with this warning.

The warning is harmless but I understand it can be frustrating.

You might want to consider either championing the developers of `HSQL` to offer this behavior or consider other in-memory database alternatives such as `H2` for your unit tests that support such syntax.